# Is there a RanDAO on Ethereum (Eth1)?

Tags: solidity

The only place I can find any mention of the RanDAO contract addresses is in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4uv35j/randao_10/). Looking at them in [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb2A1ac7F7253B0EBF6410920ED1342c974bcA67A) shows that the last time they were used were used was ~1600 days ago, around the time of their creation.

Comment: Whoah, 1600 days. I somehow thought it's much newer. Haven't heard of the project for a year or so, but I somehow thought it would be in use already for quite some time - maybe I was wrong. Can't also find anything in google either...